# Java crypto, reset the IV possible for performance improvement?

Tags: java, performance, scala, encryption

I create an encryption cipher as follows (in Scala, using bouncy-castle)

```
  def encryptCipher(secret:SecretKeySpec, iv:IvParameterSpec):Cipher = {
    val e = Cipher.getInstance("AES/GCM/NoPadding")
    e.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, secret, iv)
  }
```

You see that the slow operation of generating the key spec is already handled.  However calling init itself for each message is too slow.
I'm currently processing 50K messages, and calling the init method adds nearly 4 seconds.

Is there a way to re-initialise with a new IV which is not so time intensive?

Comment: What do the [Javadocs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/crypto/Cipher.html#doFinal()) say about this? They seem to answer your question completely.

Comment: Sure, I was wondering if there was a better approach. 
Incidently I found a significant gain from moving from Bouncy Castle AES/GCM to Java AES/CBC

Comment: Also got latest version of JDK 7 which comes with native AES processing on IntelliJ chips

Comment: Is your Iv the same across all messages? If yes, you can use a ThreadLocal

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no standard way to do that in the standard library,
but there's a good workaround if you're using AES:

The purpose of the IV is to eliminate the possibility that same plain texts encrypt into the same cipher texts.

You can just "update" (as in `Cipher.update(byte[])`) with a random block-size byte array before encrypting (and with the same block when decrypting). This is almost exactly the same as using the same random block as IV.

To see that, run this snippet (that uses the above method to generate **exactly** the same cipher text - but this is just for compatibility with other platforms, there's no need to calculate a specific IV for it to be secure.

```
Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
SecureRandom secureRandom = new SecureRandom();

byte[] keyBytes = new byte[16];
secureRandom.nextBytes(keyBytes);
SecretKeySpec key = new SecretKeySpec(keyBytes, "AES");

byte[] plain = new byte[256];
secureRandom.nextBytes(plain);

// first init using random IV (save it for later)
cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key, secureRandom);
byte[] realIv = cipher.getIV();
byte[] expected = cipher.doFinal(plain);

// now init using dummy IV and encrypt with real IV prefix
IvParameterSpec nullIv = new IvParameterSpec(new byte[16]);
cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key, nullIv);
// calculate equivalent iv
Cipher equivalentIvAsFirstBlock = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/NoPadding");
equivalentIvAsFirstBlock.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, key, nullIv);
byte[] equivalentIv = equivalentIvAsFirstBlock.doFinal(realIv);

cipher.update(equivalentIv);
byte[] result = cipher.doFinal(plain);
System.out.println(Arrays.equals(expected, result));
```

The decryption part is easier because the result of the block-decryption is XORed with the previous cipher text (see [Block cipher mode of operation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_cipher_mode_of_operation#Cipher_Block_Chaining_.28CBC.29)), you just need to append the real IV to cipher-text, and throw it afterwards:

```
// Encrypt as before

IvParameterSpec nullIv = new IvParameterSpec(new byte[16]);
cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, key, nullIv);

cipher.update(realIv);
byte[] result = cipher.doFinal(encrypted);
// result.length == plain.length + 16
// just throw away the first block
```

Comment: Note that this answer only applies to CBC mode, whereas the original asker was asking about GCM mode.